crypto bot quantity - amount
I started coding a crypto bot via python, I am using binance(API) to trade.
from binance python library, I found this draft
order = client.order_market_buy(
    symbol='BNBBTC',
    quantity=100)


order = client.order_market_sell(
    symbol='BNBBTC',
    quantity=100)

I want to change the quantity as amount, I mean I would like to trade 20$ or 50$ per trade for example
so I want my code to make this calculation every single time.
quantity = amount(50$)/buyprice

Is there a proper way to do it? I could not add this to my code
https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/account.html#orders
I tried to define quantity as
amount = 50 # 50$ is constant value for every single trade
buy_price # the coin price and can be found when the necessary conditions are matched for example rsi< 30 and bollinger band low < close price etc
when I execute this code, it says define buy_price but I already defined it in my strategy
quantity = amount / buy_price

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

better show minimal working code

you have to define buy_price = ... with some value. If you assigned value then maybe you do it in wrong place. You didn't show code, you didn't show full error message, and we can't read in your mind - so don't expect answer. You have to show all details in question (not in comments)

you have three steps!
get the current price:
from binance.client import Client

client = Client('your_api_key', 'your_api_secret')

trading_pair = 'BNBBTC'
ticker = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol=trading_pair)
current_price = float(ticker['price'])

calculate quantity:
fixed_dollar_amount = 50 
quantity = fixed_dollar_amount / current_price

place your order: use the calculated quantity to place your market buy or sell order
